# How to create JMeter test with parallel execution in one thread group with specific throughput?

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I've got API usage statistics from production cluster and need to simulate it on test cluster, i.e. execute N requests each with specific rate per minute. I've achieved desired result with following structure (simplified):

```
- Thread Group #1
  - Auth
  - Loop Controller
    - API Request #1
    - Constant Throughput Timer #1
- Thread Group #2
  - Auth
  - Loop Controller
    - API Request #2
    - Constant Throughput Timer #2
- Thread Group #3
  ...
...
```

It is not looking good enough cause I'm forced to repeat same `Auth` and `Loop Controller` many times for each `API Request`.

I prefer to have test plan structure like this:

```
- Thread Group #1
  - Auth
  - Loop Controller
    - Some Kind of Parallel Controller
      - Simple Controller or Something Like This #1
        - API Request #1
        - Constant Throughput Timer #1
      - Simple Controller or Something Like This #2
        - API Request #2
        - Constant Throughput Timer #2
      - Simple Controller or Something Like This #3
        ...
```

The only one looking good tool to implement such solution was `bzm - Parallel Controller`, but I could not make it work with structure above. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, JMeter waits for previous [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) response prior to executing next Sampler so if you put all the Samplers under one Thread Group all the requests will be executed **at the speed of the slowest request**

So your approach with different Thread Groups is valid.

If you need to use the same common steps in several Thread Groups instead of copying and pasting them consider putting them under [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and link the Test Fragments using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) where required.

Comment: Thank you for response. Two comments: 1) If parallel execution is possible only with different Thread Groups then what for is `bzm - Parallel Controller`, that states "The Parallel Controller can be used to create parallel requests" https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter; 2) The problem of common steps is not only in copypasting elements but also in redundant auth calls for each of Thread Groups for each thread instead of one auth call and using token from it for all following steps in one Thread Group with parallel execution inside.

Comment: The Parallel Controller is mainly for bypassing JMeter limitation when it comes to i.e. simulating [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests. It is not very compatible with JMeter Threads model hence it may cause problems when it comes to i.e. cookies handling. 2. You can authenticate once either using Once Only Conroller or by [storing the token into a JMeter property using __setProperty() in one Thread Group and accessing it using __P() function from other Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups).

Comment: I've looked at Blazemeter site by your last link, but there is explicitly stated "Run Thread Groups consecutively" to achieve desired behaviour. It does not suits me obviousely if I understand all correctly.